# Implement Google Tag Manager event using Code?

Tags: google-analytics

how to implement google tag manager add to cart event using code ?
I want to implement add to cart event tracking using code in my Wordpress website.

Answer (score 0):

You can track events on Google Tag Manager by sending a `dataLayer.push` event from your website, by using JavaScript.

If you are trying to implement add to cart on enhanced ecommerce you could use the following template from Google's documentation:

```
dataLayer.push({
  'event': 'addToCart',
  'ecommerce': {
    'currencyCode': 'EUR',
    'add': {                                // 'add' actionFieldObject measures.
      'products': [{                        //  adding a product to a shopping cart.
        'name': 'Triblend Android T-Shirt',
        'id': '12345',
        'price': '15.25',
        'brand': 'Google',
        'category': 'Apparel',
        'variant': 'Gray',
        'quantity': 1
       }]
    }
  }
});
```

Once you implement this code on your website, all you need to do is to create an event tag, `enable overriding settings`, set the `Enable Enhanced Ecommerce Features` value to `True` and check the `Use dataLayer` box.

The trigger to this tag should be a custom event, and the event name should be `addToCart`, the same name you sent in the dataLayer.

Now, if all you want to do is to track the add to cart event, and you are not interested on enhanced ecommerce, you could send something like:

```
dataLayer.push({
  'event': 'addToCart',      
});
```

This way you wont need to enable overriding settings or to send information about the products.

To learn more about Enhanced Ecommerce take a look at: [Enhanced Ecommerce (UA) Developer Guid](https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/enhanced-ecommerce)

Comment: Can you please tell me one more thing, do i have to create tag on tag manager and add the mentioned code on website.
I have to implement both things ?

Comment: Each tag needs a trigger to run. If you want to run a tag by sending a code from your website, you have to add the code to the website, create a custom event trigger and add a tag to this trigger.